# htaccess - Redirect if index.html if not at end of URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having some trouble getting my `.htaccess` file to redirect correctly.

My goal is this: If the user types in a specific subdirectory, I want them to be redirected to that subdirectory/index.html. For my specific case (please keep in mind there is a special character, `~`):

`www.example.com/~helloworld/dir/`

should redirect to

`www.example.com/~helloworld/dir/index.html`

This is my `.htaccess` file in my server's root (public_html) directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^%~helloworld/dir/$
RewriteRule . /~helloworld/dir/index.html [R=302,L]
```

But it just results in the same page loading with no index.html at the end.
How can I fix this?

Edit: Thanks @MrWhite made a typo in my intended domain, just updated it.

Comment: Just use `DirectoryIndex index.html` and why do you want to show `index.html` in URLs, just showing content of `index.html` should be good enough

Comment: "redirected to that `subdirectory/index.htm`" - although your example shows a _different_ path - it looks like you are removing the first `/dir`? ie. From `/dir/~helloworld/dir/` to `/~helloworld/dir/index.html`?

Comment: "please keep in mind there is a special character, `~`" - there is nothing "special" about that character, unless this is a [per-user web directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html)?

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, that did the trick. It sounds silly, but for some reason my react app won't work in production if I don't include index.html at the end, as submit buttons will actually make an HTTP request instead of using react router dom.

Comment: "my react app won't work in production if I don't include index.html at the end" - So, is this now resolved?

Comment: @MrWhite wouldnt* work in production, it's resolved